# Querying an IQuery from a cached list returns null exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, caching

I've been experimenting with Peter Montgomery's "Caching the results of LINQ queries" source listed [here](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/caching-the-results-of-linq-queries/)

which creates an extension method for `IQueryable<T>` returning an `IEnumerable<T>` from cached data if possible. The main extension method looks like this.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the result of the query; if possible from the cache, otherwise
    /// the query is materialized and the result cached before being returned.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">The IQueryable for which to return the query.</param>
    /// <param name="priority">The relative cache priority of the object.</param>
    /// <param name="slidingExpiration">The timespan indicating the duration of the sliding expiration</param>
    /// <returns>The result of the query; if possible from the cache</returns>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of entity for which to provide the method.</typeparam>
    public static IEnumerable<T> FromCache<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, CacheItemPriority priority, TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
    {
        string key = query.GetCacheKey();

        // try to get the query result from the cache
        var result = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key) as List<T>;

        if (result == null)
        {
            // TODO: ... ensure that the query results do not
            // hold on to resources for your particular data source
            //
            //////// for entity framework queries, set to NoTracking
            //////var entityQuery = query as ObjectQuery<T>;
            //////if (entityQuery != null)
            //////{
            //////    entityQuery.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
            //////}

            // materialize the query
            result = query.ToList();

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
                key,
                result,
                null, // no cache dependency
                Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                slidingExpiration,
                priority,
                null); // no removal notification
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I use the method like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves all instances of the specified type, if possible from the cache.
    /// Objects are maintained in a <see cref="T:System.Data.EntityState.Detached">Detached</see> state and 
    /// are not tracked in the <see cref="T:System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager">ObjectStateManager</see>. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A list of all instances of the specified type.</returns>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of entity for which to provide the method.</typeparam>
    public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        //return new ObjectQuery<T>(GetSetName<T>(), this.context, MergeOption.NoTracking);
        return new ObjectQuery<T>(GetSetName<T>(), this.context, MergeOption.NoTracking).FromCache<T>().AsQueryable<T>();
    }
```

I would then filter my requests like this (Querying the AdventureWorks database sample):

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>(readonlySession.All<Product>()
.Where(x => x.Color.Equals("Black", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

My problem is that when I attempt to query the data like this I get a `NullReferenceException` as some products return null for the property `Color`. If I query the entity without the cache there is not a problem.

Can anyone explain why this happens and how I could fix the problem?

Many thanks.

UPDATE : I've since discovered using == solves my problem though I don't know why. I'd like to be able to use Equals() though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do `x.Color.Equals("Black", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` and the Color is *null* you will get the null exception, better way is to use the static string method which will work even if the parameters are *null*, like that:

```
String.Equals(x.Color, "Black", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: @ K Ivanov: Thanks for the explanation. The only reason I couldn't accept your answer is that you were beaten for time. I have up-voted your answer though.

Comment: thx, although my answer was 4 mins before the one you have selected, it is not a big deal

Answer (score 2):

It's up to the LINQ provider for the particular ORM technology you are using to translate your queries into the appropriate SQL. The EF (or L2S) provider knows how to translate `x.Color.Equals("Black", ...)` into the appropriate SQL. However, when you cache the resutls (by calling `ToList()`) you switch over to LINQ to Objects and then all the rules of C# start being applied: you can't call an instance method on a null instance of an object.

You could try switching it around: `x=>"Black".Equals(x.Color)` (hopefully the LINQ to EF provider will understand that as well, though I can't test it right now, so you'll have to try it yourself)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I was afraid the answer would be something like this. It feels a little bit weird switching the syntax but I'm sure i'll get used to it and it works. Cheers!